# Disable inline_edit() on edit.php

Tags: posts, admin, wp-admin

In the class `WP_Posts_List_Table` there is a function named `inline_edit()` and it is responsible for rendering the entire quick edit table that is used (but initially hidden) on `wp-admin/edit.php`.

I want to **prevent** that table from being rendered because the site I'm working on has thousands of category terms and they all get added to this quick edit table as list items with checkboxes. It makes `edit.php` huge and slow loading (and in certain cases with some jQuery plugins even make some browsers stall).

I have not found any way, with filters or actions in `WP_Posts_List_Table`, to prevent this table from being rendered. Nor no way to make `edit.php` *not* call `$wp_list_table->inline_edit();` at the end. Is there some (proper) way to achieve my goal? Without hacking core, of course.

(I do know how to disable the quick edit link in the post rows with `post_row_actions` filter but that huge table is still being rendered and sent with `edit.php`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to find a filter either, but there is a check for whether the taxonomy is allowed to show it's UI. So what I used to do in one of my plugins was to tweak the `$wp_taxonomies` global variable on the edit page.

```
/**
 * Disable the UI for categories, but only on EDIT screen
 * which prevents them from appearing in quick edit
 */
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'wpa_130501_disable_ui' );

function wpa_130501_disable_ui(){
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $wp_taxonomies['category']->show_ui = FALSE;
}
```

The quick-edit section needs a lot of love in a future update.

Comment: Or maybe we can turn the taxonomy NOT hierarchical the same way, so the quick edit panel keeps working and the category selector is a search based solution, like the tags

Comment: That was an improvement. At first it didn't work for me until I realized that I had to replace `category` with the name of the taxonomies used on the site, and call `->show_ui = FALSE` for each of them. This works and removes them for quick edit and my edit.php loads fast again. And quick edit remains useful for dates and titles etc.

Comment: About setting them to non-hierarchical: This can be done with `$wp_taxonomies['category']->hierarchical = FALSE;` and you get text fields with auto completion instead. BUT! They do not save correctly, I tried and lost all terms when using this on quick edit. Otherwise that would have been a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue a while, i solved it by changing the term_list with a filter tho remove all checkboxes when i'm on the edit.php page. First, you can remove the link with this:

```
    function remove_quick_edit( $actions ) {
        unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
        return $actions;
    }
    add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,1);
```

This will only remove the link, but the actual category selector is still in the source code...

```
    add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args', 'remove_terms_from_list', '', 2);
    function remove_terms_from_list( $args, $post_id){
        global $pagenow, $typenow;
        if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $typenow == 'post-type-name' || $pagenow == 'nav-menus.php') {
            $args['walker'] = new wiki_remove_tax_quickedit;
            $args['taxonomy'] = ' ';
        }
        return $args;
    }

    class wiki_remove_tax_quickedit extends Walker {
        var $tree_type = 'category';
        var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id');

        function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
                $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
                $output .= "$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
        }

        function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
                $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
                $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
        }

        function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth, $args, $id = 0 ) {

        }
    }
```

(change the post-type-name to your post type)

Comment: Ok, I haven't used the Waker class before, but I'll look into it. So this will remove all the list items, but otherwise leave the rest of the quick edit, right?

(And yes, as I said in the original question, I do know about using `post_row_actions` and what it does and does not do.)

Comment: Yes, the first part of the code(post_row_actions) will remove the Quick edit link, but the actual quick edit div is still hidden in the source code. With the walker class, i simply removed all of the options from the taxonomy terms selector list, so it won't impact your page rendering. So at the end, the quick edit div is still there, but its not "really" there:)

Comment: I corrected some minor syntax error in the code and then it worked. Your solution does remove all category terms and `edit.php` once again loads fast. While not a complete removal of all the quick edit parts nor a way to disable the call for `inline_edit()` this is the best workaround so far.

Comment: I thought that maybe I could leave the quick edit link visible (yes, I _still_ know what  `post_row_actions` does) since my editors like to use quick edit to change dates on posts. But a warning to anyone who tries this: **when the quick edit changes are saved then all terms are removed from the post** because none is selected (since they are not there to be selected any more). It would actually be nice if the quick edit could be used without messing up the categories, but as of now don't use it with this walker code.

Comment: One should also remove quick edit from the bulk action menu since it triggers the quick edit funktion.